# BM-800 sound quality question

Tags: sound-quality

Ive got myself a bm-800 mic knowing i cant run it correctly. Just want to know if a phantom power supply will remove the hissing from the mic?  If so will a Behringer UM2 Soundcard be fine?
and do i need to know anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used a BM-800 with a Behringer UM2 for recording speech for a talking newspaper (using Audacity). The readers are a couple of feet away from the microphone and hiss isn't a problem for this application. If your sound source is more distant your results may be worse. Quality seems comparable to the more expensive Blue Yeti microphone which I also use for this application.

I'd check the price of the UM2 from your suppliers against other models in the u-phoria range. When I bought my UM2 4 months ago it was considerably cheaper than the other models but has recently jumped in price from my local Amazon so for a small increase I could now step up to the next model, the UMC22, which is supposed to have a better mic pre-amp (though Behringer don't publish numerical specifications and it does have smaller, more fiddly, gain controls) or the following model, the UMC202HD, which has 10 dB more dynamic range, though again we're not told if this is a lower noise figure or just more headroom. The UMC202HD does offer up to 192 kHz sampling rather than the maximum 48 kHz sampling of the two cheaper models.

You can download the user guide for the u-phoria range (with some specifications) [here](https://mediadl.musictribe.com/media/sys_master/h70/hd5/8850095407134.pdf).